# Is it legal for a business to give a discount for paying with cash vs. credit card?

Tags: european-union, payment, credit-card

I ate at a Croatian restaurant where I had the option to pay with cash with euros or pay with my credit card.

If I chose to pay with cash, I would be given a 10% discount.

As I have a VISA credit card issued in another EU country, this discount seems to be against the law.

According to https://europa.eu/youreurope/business/finance-funding/making-receiving-payments/electronic-cash-payments/index_en.htm :

> ## Card surcharges are not allowed
>
> You're not allowed to charge your customers extra for using a credit
> or debit card. This applies to all card purchases (in shops and
> online) made throughout the EU.

So, is it a legal loophole to give discounts for paying with cash instead of adding a surcharge for paying with a credit card?

Or is this actually illegal?

Comment: https://www.cardfellow.com/blog/cash-discount-eliminate-processing-fees/

Comment: @abelenky Note that the link is referring to U.S. law on the subject. Also FYI Croatia joined the European Union in 2013 and adopted the euro on 1 January 2023.

Comment: Yes, this hack was used *for decades* by businesses all over the USA, because credit card merchant agreements prohibited surcharging for credit (but they had no standing to prevent discounting for cash).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, its legal

Economically, there is no difference between a cash discount and a card surcharge; legally, there is. That’s because the law prohibits charging *more* than the advertised price for a given payment method but doesn’t prohibit charging *less*.

Of course, it’s likely there is some illegality here but it’s not against the customer. A business doesn't give a 10% discount to avoid paying a 1-2% fee. They do it because they are not reporting (some of) their cash sales to the tax authorities and are therefore saving the 25% VAT and 18% company tax.